# How to get secret from Secret Manager in serverless

Tags: server, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-secrets-manager

I configured a secret to my RDS database. Its name is: `qa/aurora`

I am trying to make the reference on my serverless.yml in the environment settings like this:

```
DB: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/qa/aurora~true}
```

I want to use this DB environment variable to set the user and password to my Aurora database.

The problem is that I am getting this error:

```
ServerlessError: An error occurred: testLambdaFunction - Properties validation failed for resource testLambdaFunction with message:
  #/Environment/Variables/DB: expected type: String, found: JSONObject.
      at C:\Users\fer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\lib\monitorStack.js:94:23
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
      at async AwsDeploy.update (C:\Users\fer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\lib\updateStack.js:144:5)
```

According to the Serverless [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-using-aws-secrets-manager), it should be working fine with getting a JSONObject.

What I am missing to make this work?

PS: Why should I add `~true` at the end of the string to find the secret? If I remove this value i get the error:

```
A valid SSM parameter to satisfy the declaration 'ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/qa/aurora' could not be found.
```

Comment: I was working with python and aws secret manager. secret manager return json object, but you need to extract the details from it(like user name, pass, db name) and pass it as string

Answer (score 2):

The problema was that i was nesting the 3 levels down the code:

`DB: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/qa/aurora~true}`

As soon as i change it to the same level of the environment attribute it worked